# Uninstall Atomineer

Tags: documentation, uninstallation, atomineer

Looks like I am being held hostage by the Atomineer Pro Documentation add-in for Visual Studio! The trail period is over, I have no use for it!  But now everytime I do something in Visual Studio I get an error message and get sent to their web site!

I have looked all over to find out how to uninstall it and have not found away to uninstall it!

WARNING TO EVERYONE -  This Atomineer Pro is not easy to uninstall!! Just from the problems of uninstalling it, I would highly recomend no one ever installs it!

Comment: Wish I read this before installing. Won't uninstall from Windows 10

Comment: Same as @buttonsrtoys.  The thing is pretty much ransom ware.  Once you install, you're screwed.  I wish there is a way to get the words out so people won't fall into the trap.

Comment: I agree.  This software is junk.  Regardless of how well it may or may not work.  Uninstalling is terrible.  I had to delete all files I could find for it, now I get errors every time I open visual studio; still better than having the extension though.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this too running on Windows 10 and VS 2013. Ended up installing and running IObit Uninstaller, which clean up the registry, but Atomineer was still loading in Visual Studio. My second pass was to search my C: drive for "Atomineer" which got several hits including some in a VS AddIns folder (I think). I just deleted everything and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

*Visual Studio 2015 onwards (Standard VS Extension)*

- In Visual Studio, go to **Tools > Extensions and Updates**, select Atomineer from the list, and click the Uninstall button.

*Visual Studio 2005-2013 (Standard VS Add-in)*

- Use **Control Panel > Programs and Features** to uninstall it just like any other app, **or**
- Run the Atomineer installer and select "uninstall", **or**
- In the unlikely case that neither of the above work, you can manually search your drive and delete any "AtomineerUtils.Addin" files you find.

In any case if you have any problems, **email Atomineer support** and we'll be happy to help.